# What is equivalent to Bundle Identifier in xCode for Android?

Tags: android, bundle, manifest, xcode9, identifier

As Xcode has Bundle identifier for uniquely identifying the app. Hence if we change a bundle identifier it gives a totally new build. How can we do this in Android?

Comment: You have `applicationId` inside `defaultConfig` in your gradle file which uniquely identifies app on PlayStore

Answer (score 0):

change **applicationId** in **defaultConfig** at Build.gradle file. Like,

> defaultConfig {
>           applicationId "com.example.abc"
>       }